# collect data from multiple Mongoose queries and sent to route

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Just started learning Express with content available online. With pages depending on single query I'm able to manage. But I'm stuck with page where I have to build a pagination table. Here I have to call 2 queries first for total count and second for 1st page (limit 20) of dataset. I'm using Bootstrap tables which renders data after page loads through ajax call. Response should be in following format -

```
{"total":100,"rows":[{"id":"59af010d93f3cc9ab0e09b3a","email":"test@test.com"},
{"id":"59af010d93f3cc9ab0e09b3a","email":"test2@test.com"}]}}
```

I have a route file - users.js where I'm calling my model - users.js

## routes/users.js

```
const User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/userslist', (req, res) => {
  User.getUserList(req, (err, user,next) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
      return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
    }
      res.json({"rows":user});
  });  
});
module.exports = router;
```

## models/user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

module.exports.getUserList = function(req, callback){

    skip = parseInt(req.query.offset);
    nPerPage = parseInt(req.query.limit);
    sortby = req.query.sort;
    orderby = req.query.order;

    User.find().exec(function (err, count){
          User.find(callback).sort([[sortby, orderby]]).skip(skip > 0 ? (skip+1) : 0).limit(nPerPage).exec(function(err, data){
            res.json( {"total":count.length,"rows":data} );
          });
})
```

In this model file I'm trying to call 2 queries together and thats what is throwing error. But when I only call second query without res.json it works.

Please tell me what is the best practice to call multiple queries and also how can I improve my understanding on callbacks. I feel that's where I'm totally blank. If you can suggest any online content with easy examples, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the correct way to issue the callback. And your big issue was `res` is not in scope. But there are other things you really should be paying attention to.

Instead you pass the result ( data and/or error ) to the calling function and let it be resolved there:

## routes/users.js

```
const User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/userslist', (req, res, next) => {
  User.getUserList(req, (err, data) => {
    if(err) next(err);
    if(!data){
      return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
    }
    res.json(data);
  });  
});
module.exports = router;
```

## models/user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

module.exports.getUserList = function(req, callback) {

    skip = parseInt(req.query.offset);
    nPerPage = parseInt(req.query.limit);
    sortby = req.query.sort;
    orderby = req.query.order;

    User.count().exec((err, count) => {
      User.find().sort([[sortby, orderby]])
        .skip(skip > 0 ? (skip+1) : 0).limit(nPerPage)
        .exec((err, data) => {
          callback(err,{"total":count,"rows":data});
        });
    })
}
```

Or better yet, learn to use promises:

## routes/users.js

```
const User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/userslist', (req, res, next) => {
  User.getUserList(req).then(data => {
    if(!data) {
      return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
    }
    res.json(data);
  }).catch(next);
});
module.exports = router;
```

## models/user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

module.exports.getUserList = function(req) {

    skip = parseInt(req.query.offset);
    nPerPage = parseInt(req.query.limit);
    sortby = req.query.sort;
    orderby = req.query.order;

    return User.count().then(count =>
      User.find().sort([[sortby, orderby]])
        .skip(skip > 0 ? (skip+1) : 0)
        .limit(nPerPage).then(data => ({"total":count,"rows":data}))
    );

}
```

Or even modernizing with `async/await`, and making both the count and data request in parallel with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

## routes/users.js

```
const User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/userslist', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let data = await User.getUserList(req)
    if(!data) {
      return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
    }
    res.json(data);
  } catch(e) {
    next(e);
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

## models/user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

module.exports.getUserList = (req) => {

    skip = parseInt(req.query.offset);
    nPerPage = parseInt(req.query.limit);
    sortby = req.query.sort;
    orderby = req.query.order;

    return Promise.all([
      User.count().then(count => ({ total: count })),
      User.find().sort([[sortby, orderby]])
        .skip(skip > 0 ? (skip+1) : 0)
        .limit(nPerPage)
        .then( data => ({ rows: data }))
    ]).then(result => result.reduce((acc,curr) =>
      Object.assign(acc,curr),{})
    );

}
```

In either case, it's not the task of you model function to return data through the controller. Instead you pass the data back and let the method on the controller actually perform the output.

> Also note using [`.count()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count) is preferable to `.find()` and then getting the length of the resulting array. The former is far more efficient as it gets the result count from the "cursor" without actually needing to iterate and return all the documents from the cursor, which is what the latter is doing.

Comment: Thanks Neil. your code is working perfectly. But I couldn't understand last 2 lines, Can you please explain -
]).then(result => result.reduce((acc,curr) =>
      Object.assign(acc,curr),{})

Comment: @Shrikant If you look at [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) you will see the intent is to "run both operations in parallel" as opposed to "in series" as requests, which is for efficiency. The return result of this comes in the form of an array resulting from the "array of promises" submitted. The [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b) method "combines" these results into a single object. Just like you are asking.

Comment: @Shrikant The overall point is that "all approaches" are actually doing the same thing with the same result. It's just showing how to do the same thing in different ways. The main correction common to all is the actual handling and how that differs from what you attempted. That part is fully explained in the question already.